# How to comprehend the python regex compile matching result: `re.compile(r'a*')`

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'a*')

pattern.findall("aba")
```

result:

```
['a', '', 'a', '']
```

Why there is empty matches in the result? How to comprehend this?

To be more specific, what do the two empty matches--**''** in the result stand for in the string **"aba"**?

Comment: @U9-Forward Didn't you edit the ugly title as well?

Comment: @U9-Forward Good job, bro!

Answer (score 0):

*findall(pattern, string, flags=0)¶*

Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. **Empty matches are included in the result.**

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain, as I also could not find good information on the outputs.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.findall) states that

> **`re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`**
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Non-empty matches can now start just after a previous empty match.

```
import re

text = 'abcaad'
print(f"'a'  matches {re.findall('a' , text)}")
print(f"'a+' matches {re.findall('a+', text)}")
print(f"'a*' matches {re.findall('a*', text)}")
print(f"'z*' matches {re.findall('z*', text)}")
```

The output is

```
'a'  matches ['a', 'a', 'a']
'a+' matches ['a', 'aa']
'a*' matches ['a', '', '', 'aa', '', '']
'z*' matches ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

1. `a` matches exactly the character `a` thrice.
2. `a+` matches **one** or **more** occurrences of character `a`.
3. `a*` matches **zero** or **more** occurrences of character `a`.
   Besides matching `a` and `aa`, it also **does not** matches `b`, `c`, `d` and the whole string.
4. `z*` matches **zero** or **more** occurrences of character `z`.
   It **does not** matches `a`, `b`, `c`, `a`, `a`, `d` and the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `a*`.  `*` matches zero or more repetitions of the character.  So `b` matches `a*`, and so does anything else.  It seems like you want `a+` instead, which matches one or more repetitions of the character.